# CVTRES : fatal error CVT1106: cannot write to file

Tags: visual-c++, linker-errors

Moving a project to different computer and trying to compile it there, produces the following error:

```
CVTRES : fatal error CVT1106: cannot write to file
.\Debug\Project.res : fatal error LNK1123: failure during conversion to COFF: file invalid or corrupt
```

Environment is Visual C++ 6, but quick search from the internet hinted that it might occur in newer versions also. Both computers are working and able to compile other projects. Also, permissions are not the problem.

What possible reasons there are for this kind of error?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Problem was as the error message says: cannot write to file.

Just, the file it was trying to write is supposedly in temporary folder. The temp folder was on a drive, which had only a little space left. It was enough to compile most projects, but not enough to compile this one, since the exe included many files as resources.